# Browserify: Can't seem to get reactify to work with coffeeify

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I can't seem to get `reactify` to work with `coffeeify`. I followed the Reactify's readme to no avail.

#### app.coffee

```
### @jsx React.DOM ###

console.log 'hi'
```

#### browser command:

```
browserify -t coffeeify -t [ reactify -x coffee] ./src/coffeescripts/app.coffee                                               
/Users/mueller.128/repos/klc/react_colorpicker/src/coffeescripts/app.coffee:1
/** @jsx React.DOM */
^
ParseError: regular expressions cannot begin with `*`
```

#### my attempt at using the browserify api in a gulp task

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source     = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watchify   = require('watchify');
var coffeeify  = require('coffeeify');
var reactify   = require('reactify');


gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  return browserify('./src/coffeescripts/app.coffee')
    .transform({ }, coffeeify)
    .transform({ extension: "coffee" }, reactify)
    .bundle({debug: true})
    .pipe(source('./src/bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/javascripts/'));
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with browserify, but it looks like you're running the CoffeeScript transform twice on accident.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks for the quick response. Where am I running the CoffeeScript transform twice? Thanks!

I enjoyed your articles on React btw. Also, Perseus is pretty awesome.

Comment: I'm not sure (as I said, I'm not really familiar with browserify), but the "regular expressions cannot begin with \`*\`" error you're getting is one that the CoffeeScript compiler would emit when seeing `/** @jsx React.DOM */` (which is what the output should be from `###* @jsx React.DOM ###`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browserify -t coffeeify -t [ reactify -x] ./app.coffee
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue -- `` ParseError: regular expressions cannot begin with `*` `` -- when using `coffee-reactify` as duereg suggests. Following [the recipe from the gulp recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/e463249a8cd523de60008d152522e946a108cbee/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md) led me to this:

```
bundler = browserify 'test.cjsx', {
  transform : [ require 'coffee-reactify' ]
}
```

...which exhibited the issue. Some ad-hoc logging in browserify revealed it's some kind of subtle bug where the transforms get added twice when specified in this way, confirming Ben's suspicion that the compiler was running twice. Changing it to the following:

```
bundler = browserify 'test.cjsx'
bundler.transform require 'coffee-reactify'
```

...fixed the issue entirely.

A functioning example:

```
gulp       = require 'gulp'
gutil      = require 'gulp-util'
browserify = require 'browserify'
source     = require 'vinyl-source-stream'

bundler = browserify './test.cjsx'
bundler.transform require 'coffee-reactify'

bundle = ->
  return bundler.bundle()
    .on 'error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error')
    .pipe source 'all-scripts.js'
    .pipe gulp.dest './.dist'

gulp.task 'default', ->
  bundle()
```

Where `test.cjsx` is just:

```
# @cjsx React.DOM
```

Someone recently opened [a ticket on browserify's github](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1124).

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with the following gulp task. Note that you'll have to install the [coffee-reactify](https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-reactify) plugin for this to work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/coffeescripts/app.coffee', { read: false })
    .pipe(browserify({
      debug: true
      transform: ['coffee-reactify'],
      extensions: ['.coffee']
    }))
    .pipe(rename('./src/bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/javascripts/'))
});
```